uninstall unmanaged package considerations
My understanding is that when uninstalling a managed package, that will basically remove everything, but this is not the case with unmanaged packages.
Salesforce does not seem to have documentation about uninstalling unmanaged packages, but their text about uninstalling managed package is as follows:
"Uninstalling a managed package removes its components and data from the org. During the uninstall process, any customizations, including custom fields or links, that you’ve made to the package are removed...If you’re uninstalling a package that includes a custom object, all components on that custom object are also deleted. Deleted items include custom fields, validation rules, custom buttons, and links, workflow rules, and approval processes."
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_uninstalling_packages.htm&type=5
Can someone (sfdcfox?) detail the considerations for uninstalling both managed and unmanaged packages, including potential issues such as components and metadata not being fully removed, and any other relevant factors?
Thanks,
Mark

Uninstalling any kind of package always has the same result. All components of the package are permanently removed from the org. Make a backup of any data and/or metadata you want to retain. The uninstall process will allow you to retained deleted data (but not metadata) for 2 days, if you choose the option. You cannot uninstall a package of any kind of it would result in breaking the org. For example,  if a Visualforce page outside the package references a class inside the package, you would first have to either delete or modify the page so it no longer references the class before you can uninstall the package.

Thanks, I appreciate the response. I wonder why there's so much online chatter of uninstalled unmanaged packages not completely removing components. Was that the case in the past?

@zargosh It was never the intent of unmanaged packages to not remove all the metadata they create. That said, it's entirely possible that bugs have existed in the past that may have left metadata behind, though I don't know of any bugs that were widespread enough to be noticeable.

cool, thanks @sfdcfox. I appreciate the help.
